# MySQL recommends lower case table names for InnoDB

Tags: mysql, windows, innodb, case-sensitive

The MySQL documentation [1] explains the possibility of using case sensitive table names on all plattforms (by setting `lower_case_table_names=0` on Unix and `lower_case_table_names=2` on Windows)...with one exception:

> Exception: If you are using InnoDB tables and you are trying to avoid these data transfer problems, you should set lower_case_table_names to 1 on all platforms to force names to be converted to lowercase.

My questions are:

- Why is it recommended to use lower case table names for InnoDB?
- What can happen if you set up InnoDB tables to be case sensitive?

[1] https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE abc (...); -- creates file `abc.frm`
CREATE TABLE ABC (...); -- creates file `ABC.frm`
```

If the OS (such as Windows) does not distinguish between `abc.frm` and `ABC.frm`, then those two tables cannot coexist.  Similarly for databases.

Also, if you get sloppy and say both

```
SELECT ... FROM abc ...;
SELECT ... FROM Abc ...;
```

There can be confusion as to what table is desired.  Hence, the setting also applies to use in queries.

Comment: This point is clear to me. And I also know about possibility to configure Windows case sensitive. My question is, why MySQL recommends **not to configure case sensitivity for the InnoDB engine**.

Comment: Windows is case insensitive.  No choice there.

Comment: That is simply not true. Did you even read my post or the documentation?